# App.js refused to apply style, refused to execute script

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I have read similar questions and the answers all revolved around correcting a line like this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Unfortunately nothing I've read has fixed the issue.

In my index.html I have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/style.css">
<script src="public/js/bundle.js"></script>
```

and in my app.js im using :

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

When I visit the page the console logs

> localhost/:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/public/css/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

and

> GET http://localhost:3000/public/js/bundle.js 404 (Not Found)
>
> localhost/:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/public/js/bundle.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Comment: If I had to guess… you're sending the wrong mime type, and you have strict mime type checking enabled. But I'm just basing that on the error saying that's exactly your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a "/" at the end of public, like so:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));
```

and removing "public/" in:

```
<script src="js/bundle.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

fixed the issue.